# How do you record earlier part of a livestream with youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

There are excellent solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040798/how-do-you-use-youtube-dl-to-download-live-streams-that-are-live/37074870) for recording a livestream with youtube-dl. However, when watching a livestream on YouTube, it's possible to back the stream up. Is it possible to do this with youtube-dl? If possible, "from beginning of livestream"?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is not possible with youtube-dl though other solutions are available (they're easily findable with a search so I won't post them here to not look like shilling).

Comment: Is there a free tool/way to do this?

Comment: There is an ongoing request here: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/21255