# How to download a YouTube livestream while it's live?

Tags: youtube

I need to rip a YT livestream while it's live. How can I do this?

I used to use this method some months back:
[How do you use youtube-dl to download live streams (that are live)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040798/how-do-you-use-youtube-dl-to-download-live-streams-that-are-live/37074870)

Sadly, it no longer works. As an example, I tried using it with the following stream:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21X5lGlDOfg

But nothing happens when I run the following command:

```
youtube-dl.py --list-formats https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21X5lGlDOfg
```

So how can I rip currently live livestreams now?

Comment: The other answer still works as of 2022, maybe you had a temporary issue at the time you tried.