# Is there any command in specific to record a part of a livestream that still is in transmission?

Tags: youtube-dl, youtube-livestreaming-api, yt-dlp

The livestream doesn't end (for now, and if ended, I think will be erased of YouTube, that's my reason to download), actually, the video is still in transmission, you know, like the streams of the NASA or streams of channels news. The detail is that the transmission lasts about 10-11 hours, and the transmission has lasted about 3 days. So it was a matter of time before the first concerts were no longer available to watch on the broadcast.

This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rE6QI0ywr0c
I want to download some concerts, but the things that I wanted, are disappearing with the passing of time. Right now, I'm only interested in the Disclosure concert. His concert starts at approximately -3:38:12. I mention it in case someone wants to help me.

I was trying this command, but only appear a text that i don't understand (I'll post it in the comments, all the images with his info). The command is this → yt-dlp.exe -f (bestvideo+bestaudio/best) "link" --postprocessor-args "ffmpeg:-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:00" -o "%(title)s_method1.%(ext)s"
The idea of that command emerged on this ideas
https://www.reddit.com/r/youtubedl/wiki/howdoidownloadpartsofavideo/
https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues/686

Also, I was trying to do this [How do you use youtube-dl to download live streams (that are live)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040798/how-do-you-use-youtube-dl-to-download-live-streams-that-are-live/37074870#37074870), but I can't get the HLS m3u8 URL in Chrome and Chrome Dev (yes, I go to F12 (Chrome Developer Tools) - Network and I write m3u8, I didn't find anything.

I should mention that I don't have extensive knowledge on codes and yt-dlp. I only learned the necessary to download videos, you know, yt-dlp.exe -F (link) and then yt-dlp.exe -f (numbers of resolution and audio) (link).
So if you recommend any programs or commands, please let me know as precisely as possible.

Any new info I'm gonna update in the comments.

PS: sorry for my english

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ati.jpg

Well, i can't put the image, but there's a link that was created
This happens when I try the command → yt-dlp.exe -f (bestvideo+bestaudio/best) "link" --postprocessor-args "ffmpeg:-ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:00" -o "%(title)s_method1.%(ext)s"